# Update query on sqlite3 does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

Update query on Sqlite3 Does not work

```
-(void)updateAlarms:(AlarmsBean *)todoItem//TodoItem: (AlarmsBean*)todoItem
{
    if (_updateAlarmsStatement == NULL)
    {
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, 

    "UPDATE AlarmSetting SET Sound = ?, Sensitivity = ?, Label = ? , Repeat = ? ,
 time = ? , On_Off = ? WHERE ID = ?",
                           -1, 
                           &_updateAlarmsStatement, 
                           NULL);
    }
    sqlite3_reset(_updateAlarmsStatement);
    sqlite3_bind_text(_updateAlarmsStatement, 1,
 [todoItem.AlarmSoundName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(_updateAlarmsStatement, 2, todoItem.AlarmSensitivity);
    sqlite3_bind_text(_updateAlarmsStatement, 3, [todoItem.AlarmName UTF8String], -1,
 SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_bind_int(_updateAlarmsStatement, 4, todoItem.AlarmRepeat);

    sqlite3_bind_text(_updateAlarmsStatement, 5, [todoItem.AlarmTime UTF8String], -1,
 SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_bind_int(_updateAlarmsStatement, 6, todoItem.AlarmOnOff);
    sqlite3_bind_int(_updateAlarmsStatement, 7, todoItem.AlarmID);
    sqlite3_step(_updateAlarmsStatement);
}
```

In other class:

```
AlarmsBean * todoItem1 = [[AlarmsBean alloc] init];

database = [[ClassAlarmDB alloc] init];

            todoItem1.AlarmID = 1 ;
            todoItem1.AlarmSoundName = @"28.png";
            todoItem1.AlarmSensitivity = 1 ;
            todoItem1.AlarmName = @"ahmad" ;
            todoItem1.AlarmRepeat = 1;
            todoItem1.AlarmTime = @"00 : Am";
            todoItem1.AlarmOnOff = 4 ;
              NSLog (@"Befor Update");
            [database updateAlarms: todoItem1];
```

But the database is not updated.

Comment: What is the error message? Do you already have a row with `id==1` in that table?

Comment: yes i have row id = 1  but  no error message and DataBasa is not updating

Comment: where is your database file stored on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Check the return code from `sqlite3_step(..)`, and probably also `sqlite3_prepare_v2(..)`.  If it's not `SQLITE_OK` or `SQLITE_DONE`, print out `sqlite3_errcode(_database)` and `sqlite3_errmsg(_database)`.

This should give you some information to go on.

Comment: all statement is true - but database is not updating